# Datatables not showing correct values

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using Datatable for a table that has eight same columns and three different columns based on which radio button is pressed. The table is populated by an ajax call to a python method and the data is appended to the table body.

The three columns that are different are separated by class. Based on the radio button which is pressed, the classes is either shown or hidden

```
  function show_hide_tab(a)
        {
            if(a=="tab_a")
            {
                $(".tab_b").hide();
                $(".tab_a").show();
            }
            else
            {
                $(".tab_b").hide();
                $(".tab_a").show();
            }

        }
```

The problem I am facing is this:

For the tab_a, all values are being shown correctly. For tab_b the columns that are unique to tab_b only have values for the first 10 default rows. When I switch to more than 10 entries on a page, the columns show empty. Similarly, if I move to the second page, the columns are empty. The weird part is, that if I am on page 2 on tab tab_b and click on page 2 on tab_a and then come back to tab_b, I get the correct values in the column. An example of a table cell in tab_b:

```
upd += '<td class="tab_b" style="display: none;"><center><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="initiatereturn(\'' + data[i]['orderid'] + '&' + data[i]['memberid'] + '&' + data[i]['amount'] + '\');">Return</button></center></td>';
```

where data holds the values pulled from database.

Comment: Might need a jsfiddle to figure out the problem. What does initiatereturn function do?

Comment: maybe the problem is that when datatable is applied to the table, only the first 10 rows exist. Any manipulation of the table needs to be reapplied when the 'next page'  is loaded

Comment: @Michael: No, the entire result set's HTML is appended to the table. And then the datatable is initialized

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar: It's an independent function that has nothing to do with the table. The other two dissimilar columns are pure text and they don't work correctly either.

Comment: One possible way of doing it is loading all rows, and then immediately enabling pagination after load completes. Is there any to do this in Datatables?

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing the *drawCallback* function which gets called everytime the table refreshes.

```
jQuery('#'+table_id).dataTable({
  "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
     // check the selected radio buttons and show/hide the columns
  }
});
```

Comment: The same problem persists. The data in tab_b is only populated if I visit the corresponding page in tab_a

Comment: Can you share any jsfiddle? I'd see the problem directly then.